# Coupling a SQL database through a urllib2 to a Python application

Tags: python, sql, urllib2

Momentarily I am creating a python based application through the programme Ren'py. Now I have to couple the game with a SQL database. The admin on the board of the programme recommended using urllib to do this.

http://lemmasoft.renai.us/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=29954

This is my thread. Now, I've managed to succesfully add the urllib to the program, but I'm lost at the entire "talk to a web service, which would then talk to the sqlite database" segment. Could you perhaps provide any hints/ tips?

I've never worked with Python before, so it's kind of challenging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer you got on that forum isn't very helpful, in that the poster didn't really explain what they meant.

urllib is really the most minor component of the solution they're suggesting. What they actually mean is that you set up an entire web service, hosted on a URL somewhere, which talks to its own database. Your local installations of the app would then use a Python web library to communicate with that remote database over the web.

While this isn't particularly difficult, it is a fair amount of work, especially if you don't have any experience in doing this. You'll need a Python web framework and somewhere to host it. Since you talk about admins needing to log in and view data, you might want to explore [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com), which comes with a built-in admin interface.

You'll then need to design an API to allow your Ren'py app to communicate with that web service, and you might want to look at the [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for that. The final part is getting your app to talk to the web service, which is where the recommendation of urllib comes in - but to be honest, that isn't even a very good recommendation here: the third-party library [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.org) would be much better.

As I say, there's quite a lot of work. A much simpler solution would be to use Python's built-in [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) library to talk to a local database via SQL, but that wouldn't do anything to make people's data available in a central location and would be open to anyone who worked out how to query the database.

Comment: Well, I have until tomorrow (27/01/2015) to finish this assignment, so I suppose I'll go with the sqllite3 for now. Not many alternatives. I'll mention it for the future project group however to work with Django, they'll have more time than I do. 

Thanks for your help Daniel Roseman, if you don't mind I'll copy/ paste your advice and save it in a document for the other group.